# In quick sort if split is 5 : n-5, then time complexity will be?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, pivot, quicksort, analysis

How do you the find complexity of quick sort when ratio between partition sizes is 5:n-5 or something like 1:19? I do not really understand how to calculate the complexity of the algorithm in these situations.

Comment: Can you fix the text in your question, because I have no idea what exactly you are asking.

Comment: If you're asking "does the complexity of quick sort change if I choose a pivot element from somewhere other than the exact middle?" then see [Quicksort#choice of pivot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, keep the following in mind:

- If you split an array into two pieces defined by some fixed ratio of a:b at each point, after O(log n) splits, the subarrays will be down to size 0.
- If you split an array into two pieces where one size is a constant k, it will take Θ(n / k) splits to get the subarray sizes to drop to 0.

Now, think about the work that quicksort does at each level of the recursion. At each layer, it needs to do work proportional to the number of elements in the layer. If you use the first approach and have something like a 1/20 : 19/20 split, then there will be at most n elements per layer but only O(log n) layers, so the total work done will be O(n log n), which is great.

On the other hand, suppose that you always pull off five elements. Then the larger array at each step will have sizes n, n - 5, n - 10, n - 15, ..., 10, 5, 0. If you work out the math and sum this up, this works out to Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) total work, which is not very efficient.

Generally speaking, try to avoid splitting off a fixed number of elements at a time in quicksort. That gives you the degenerate case that you need to worry about.